# How to hide ngForm's validator's error messages after button click

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I am struggling with resetting an `ngForm`'s errors once any button on the form has been clicked. It seems that the `formDirective.submitted` is toggled to true even after the `resetForm()` method is called. I do not understand why calling the `formDirective.resetForm()` is not having the expected result.

Template:

```
<button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="testClick()"></button>
```

Component:

```
@ViewChild(FormGroupDirective) queryFormDir: FormGroupDirective;
...

testClick() {
    this.queryFormDir.resetForm();
}
```

Clicking the `TestClick` button results in the `formDirective.submitted` state to `true` which is incorrect from what I can tell.

According to the [Angular API](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgForm) the `resetForm()` method is the correct one for resetting the `submitted` state but I am not having the expected behaviour.

I have also tried playing around with an `ErrorStateMatcher` and noticed that when I omit `isSubmitted` from the below, the validator's error messages do not show on submit at all which is not what I want but does show the relationship between the validator's error messages and the `submitted` state which is my issue.

```
export class MyErrorStateMatcher implements ErrorStateMatcher {
  isErrorState(control: FormControl | null, form: FormGroupDirective | NgForm | null): boolean {
    const isSubmitted = form && form.submitted;
    return !!(control && control.invalid && (control.dirty || control.touched || isSubmitted));
  }
}
```

My Angular version is 7.2.2

How do I reset my form so that the validator's error messages are hidden after clicking a button on the form?

**Edit:**

The example above is a simplified version of my situation. The issue crops up after the form is submitted correctly for the first time with valid data. The form is designed for multiple submissions. After the first submission the validators are triggered which is not user friendly. I want the validators to not trigger after a valid submission is completed and the form is reset.

**Edit 2:**

As requested the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1usekh).

Comment: How do you submit form when you have errors? Once you fixed the errors then you should be able to submit it and the errors disappear?

Comment: read again, he is asking to reset. not to submit. :)

Comment: The example above is a simplified version of my situation. The issue crops up after the form is submitted correctly for the first time with valid data. The form is designed for multiple submissions. After the first submission the validators are triggered which is not user friendly. I want the validators to not trigger after a valid submission is completed and the form is reset.

Comment: check my answer, reset everytime and set the errors to null.

Comment: Add `type="reset"` to your button. This will not mark the form submitted.

Comment: Could you create a stackblitz for this, would be much easier to help.

Comment: Sure, please see Edit 2 section for the link

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
testClick() {
    this.queryFormDir.reset();
    this.queryFormDir.setErrors(null);
}
```

Comment: This code doesn't work but I am guessing that you are referring to setting the errors on each of the controls within the form. I did try this however it changes the validation behavior of the targeted controls for successive form submissions essentially disabling my validation. setError is meant for manual validation.

Answer (score 0):

The following might help:

Reference your form:

```
@ViewChild("myForm")
myForm: NgForm;
```

And reset:

```
testClick() {
 this.myForm.form.markAsPristine();
 this.myForm.form.markAsUntouched();
 this.myForm.form.updateValueAndValidity();
}
```

`markAsPristine()`: This marks the form as it's original condition like new and fresh.

`markAsUntouched():` This makes the form untouched condition. User did not interact yet or no events triggered on ti.

`updateValueAndValidity():` Recalculates the value and validation status of the control.

Set the following attributes to your button for fixing:

> Clicking the TestClick button results in the formDirective.submitted
>   state to true which is incorrect from what I can tell.

`type="reset"`

Comment: Thanks Maihan. Unfortunately the additions to testClick() did not change the behavior. Changing the type of the button though does have an impact however I need to be able to control when to reset the form based on conditions, which is why I was trying to use formReset(). With type="reset", my form is forced to reset.

Answer (score 0):

Add type="button" to your button which will prevent validation error messages

```
<button type="button" color="primary" (click)="testClick()">Test Click</button>
```